# Does Markdown have an option of laying a list horizontal out?

Tags: markdown

I want to create a list of things, that would be in Markdown presented in a horizontal form like this, but so that every item is bulleted.

- List item - List item - List item

---

Comment: Markdown doesn't concern itself with presentation. Which Markdown tool are you using? And are you targeting HTML? You might be able to do this with CSS, but it will depend on the tool and possibly the environment.

Comment: Well yes, that was my initial way of thinking. I am aware of the syntax and the service that Markdown offers, just was wondering if any of the so called flavours of Markdown offer anything close to what my task is.

Comment: In that case this is off-topic as it asks us to find or recommend an off-site resource (in this case a Markdown library or tool). You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Ok, I thought so. I will check it out. Thanks.